# Android butterknife Unable to bind views into ViewHolder

Tags: android

in `recyclerview` adapter i have some view in layout and i want to bind that with `butterknife` library, but i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to bind views for ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject.Adapters.ViewHolders.
StoreListsViewHolder
at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind
```

error when i run application

My adapter:

```
public class StoreListsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreListsViewHolder> {

    OnCardClickListner onCardClickListner;
    List<StoreLists> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public StoreListsAdapter(List<StoreLists> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public StoreListsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View                     v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.store_item_fields, parent, false);
        StoreListsViewHolder holder = new StoreListsViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StoreListsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.store_title.setText(list.get(position).getStoreTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

and My `ViewHolder` class:

```
public class StoreListsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.store_lists_root)
    public LinearLayout store_lists_root;

    @Bind(R.id.store_count_vitrin)
    public TextView store_title;

    public StoreListsViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all of `R.id.XXX` if one of them miss or not in your layout (`store_item_fields.xml`) it through exception. your ViewHolder class is seems okay.

Also for finding your problem faster I recommend to empty your `viewHolder` ( it's shouldn't through any exception) and then add your fields one by one.

Also try to use new version of [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) 8.0.1;

Comment: i can binding views by `findViewsById` but i want to use `butterknife` instead of that

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy it's fairly easy. But butterknife sensitive to Id's if you miss one of them and want to use that it through exception.

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy see my adapter here as an example: https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/hadifar/dope/ui/adapter/ListAdapter.java